# Is there a way to specify replacement for shx file in translate api

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a dwg file when I open it on my pc use "DWG TrueView 2019". It will prompt "One or more SHX files are missing". I can specify a replacement or ignore there shx files. If I ignore these files the text in the file will disappear. So usually I will specify a replacement.

But when I use Model Derivative API to translate this dwg file into svf. I can not specify a replacement. So the text in the file will not show after translate. Is there a way to handle this?

The font is some type of chinese

I use Design Automation API to Plot the dwg file to pdf. But the problem still here. No text show in the pdf.

I just expect the text can show in the converted file. Whatever the font.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try enclose the font in a ZIP archive along with the drawing and translate together - see tutorial [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-source-file-to-stl/) for details and basically your post job for the translation should look like:

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "urnOfArchiveWithFont" ,
        "compressedUrn":true,
        "rootFilename":"filename.dwg"
    },
    "output": {
        "destination": {
            "region": "us"
        },
        "formats": [
        {
            "type": "svf",
            "views":["2d", "3d"]
        }]
    }
}
```

When plotting with our Design Automation services you'd need to enclose your fonts in the app bundle under `Contents` folder and refer to that path in `SupportPath` of your `PackageContents.xml`:

```
<Components>
    <RuntimeRequirements
        OS="Win64"
        Platform="AutoCAD" 
        SupportPath="./Contents/"/>
    ...
</Components>
```